# Focusing a label in Windows Form Application in C#

Tags: focus, label

I have one split container.
    In panel1 of split container, it has 2 PANEL, first panel contains 2 buttons and 1 combobox. second panel contains 2 labels. I had tried to set tabIndex of label control to 0
but when I run program button gets focus by default. When I press TAB key, next button gets focus after that "combobox" gets focus after that again button1 gets focus. But label never get the focus. Why it is so and hoe to solve this ? I want label to get focus or I wish those buttons and combo will never receive a focus.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

You can't set focus on a label because labels do not accept input. Only controls that accept input can be focussed.